# Changing sources on videosphere updates DOM but doesn't render

Tags: javascript, aframe

I have two video assets which I would like to switch between based on a user interaction.

```
<a-assets>
  <video id="video" src="./<filename>.mp4" autoplay loop crossorigin></video>
  <video id="video2" src="./<filename>.mp4" autoplay loop crossorigin></video>
</a-assets>
```

These assets are referenced in a videosphere within the same `<a-scene>`.

```
<a-videosphere id="videosphere" src="#video" rotation="0 270 0"></a-videosphere>
```

When the interactive element, an `<a-sphere>`, is focused by the camera cursor, logic is triggered which swaps the videosphere source and plays the new video.

```
document.querySelector('<interactive element>').addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
  var videosphere = document.querySelector('#videosphere');
  videosphere.setAttribute('src', '#video2');

  var video = document.querySelector(videosphere.getAttribute('src'));
  video.play();
});
```

The event fires successfully and the `src` change is reflected in the DOM, but the new video is not rendered. I have tried using `<a-sky>` in place of `<a-videosphere>` but with the same result.

Both videos play as expected when set as the default `src` of `<a-videosphere>`. For repro purposes, I'm testing in `Firefox Nightly 55.0a1`

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that changing the `material` attribute works while changing the `src` attribute does not.

`videosphere.setAttribute('src', '#video'); // NO CHANGE`
`videosphere.setAttribute('material', 'src: #video;'); // SUCCESS`

[see aframevr issue #2636](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/2636)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this:

```
videosphere.setAttribute('src', './<video2>.mp4');
```

Instead of this:

```
videosphere.setAttribute('src', '#video2');
```